# Convert reflection spectrum to optical density

Tags: reflection, density

I have the spectrum 380-780 nm at 10 nm intervals of a nearly grey patch. I need to input its optical density into a calibrating programme. This is what a densitometer would do - but I don't have one and I don't know what the densitometer would be measuring. Is there a formula for making the translation? And I have 104 patches to convert. Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple related questions: How do I convert light with a given spectrum to an RGB color? See [this](https://scipython.com/blog/converting-a-spectrum-to-a-colour/).

How do I convert RGB to grayscale? See [this](https://www.dynamsoft.com/blog/insights/image-processing/image-processing-101-color-space-conversion/).

The idea is that lighter grayscale colors are those that appear brighter to the eye. Light appears brighter if it is more intense, and if its spectrum in in the region to which the eye is more sensitive.

You have a grey patch. Presumably you have illuminated it with light that is white - It covers the full visible spectrum. It isn't necessarily uniform at all wavelengths, but it emits enough to measure the entire range.

A colored object would reflect a different amount at each wavelength. You have a grey patch that presumably reflects roughly the same at each wavelength. You don't believe it is absolutely uniform, or you wouldn't need to measure the spectrum. So you find the fraction of light reflected at each wavelength. This determines the color of the grey patch. It is the color reflected white light would have.

The gray scale value is a weighted average of the reflectance over the visible spectrum, weighted by the sensitivity of the eye.

The last step is to convert reflectance to optical density.

$$OD = log_{10}(I_0/I) = log_{10}(reflectance)$$

Comment: As I understand, optical density is not related to colour, i,e, human eye response. The % reflection at each wavelength depends on what physical units one measures the impinging light, e.g. energy, number of quanta, etc, which in turn provides a weighting to the value at each wavelength input into the weighted average  That is my first unknown.  The next one is the equation you have kindly given.

Comment: You may be right. It is related to human eye response in that you are interested in visible light. If your grey patch reflected in the infrared, you wouldn't care. I see that OD is often measured at a single wavelength. So it depends on your application. If you have a sample that transmits a given spectrum and you want a single number that tells you how bright is the light that shines through, you would want to consider all wavelengths. If you are just measuring the number of bacteria in a specimen under monochromatic light, you would use a single wavelength.